# How to import a local js file in a polymer element for both local demo and production

Tags: javascript, polymer

When I'm running a demo locally using polymer serve, I get an error that a path to a js file is bad. This js file is used in my-imported-element, which is imported.

If I fix it here, then I get a bad path error in production when I deploy the app

How can I make the path work for both? This is also an issue with image files.

What works locally if I'm running a demo that imports my-element:

```
workerFile: "../bower_components/my-imported-element/js/Broadway/Decoder.js",
```

What works on the project server:

```
workerFile: "bower_components/my-imported-element/js/Broadway/Decoder.js",
```

As I understand it, running "polymer serve" and going to the demo will open from a made up "components/my-element" path like so:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8081/components/my-element/demo/
```

So I guess the path I need is

```
http://127.0.0.1:8081/components/my-element/bower_components/my_imported_element/js/Broadway/Decoder.js
```

Do I need to just make a hacky line in the code that checks the URL for "demo" and conditionally adds the "../" to the path? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I thought of another option - making the src path a property of the element, given a default value, and then having the demo/index.html put in the modified path in the tag like <my-element path="../bower..."> </my-element>

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use a polymer method called resolveUrl. This "Rewrites a given URL relative to the original location of the document containing the dom-module for this element. This method will return the same URL before and after vulcanization."

So far, whether I'm running this line in the individual element's demo page, or importing the element from somewhere else, the path works out perfectly.

```
workerFile: this.resolveUrl("js/Broadway/Decoder.js")
```